# tachometer problem

Tags: electrical

The tachometer on my Opel vita gets crazy and starts to bounce after engine moves for a few minutes, then I lose throttle power-cant accelerate and engine stop. the vehicle then starts and stops a few seconds later. it gets normal when it rests and engine gets cold. What could be the problem?

Comment: Any stored codes?

Comment: What are stored codes?

Comment: Diagnostic trouble codes. You need some form of scantool or code reader to access them. Is the malfunction indicator lamp on?

Comment: Malfunction indicator lamp is not on. I have not used a diagnostic tool.

Comment: A few of my personal cars present similar symptoms when the vehicle speed sensor fails...only the erratic display is respective to the speedometer.